# read xls from blob using alaSql

Tags: javascript, alasql

I started using alaSQL and looks very promising, the example seems so simple in reading XLS file but I cant make it to work.

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" name="files"/>

function testxls() {
            var f = fileinput.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var data = e.target.result;
                var res = alasql('SELECT * FROM XLS(' + e + ')');
                console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
            };
        }
```

it is throwing an error that cannot read from undefined property. Any lead or help will be greatly appreciated